# How do I remove certain parts of cells in a column using Python?

Tags: python

So I have a column of strings of numbers in which certain cells have words ahead of the strings. It looks a little something like this:

| Names | Values |
| --- | --- |
| First | '9.90' |
| Second | '9.68' |
| Third | '9.45' |
| Fourth | 'Loan fee:8.10' |
| Fifth | '9.98' |

Now I've tried a lot of different ideas just to get the 'Loan fee:' removed, basically i first converted it into a list called newz and then tried

```
e=[]
for i in newz:
    i.replace('Loan fee:','')
    e.append(i)
```

Tried using regex as well:

```
def change(i):
    re.sub('Loan fee:','',i)

result = list(map(lambda x: change(x),newz))
```

So far nothing's worked

Comment: Save the variable. `i.replace('Loan fee:','')` should be `i=i.replace('Loan fee:','')` and `re.sub('Loan fee:','',i)` should be `return(re.sub('Loan fee:','',i))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Names': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'],
    'Values': ['9.90', '9.68', '9.45', 'Loan fee:8.10', '9.98']
})

df['Values'] = df['Values'].str.replace('Loan fee:', '')
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
    Names Values
0   First   9.90
1  Second   9.68
2   Third   9.45
3  Fourth   8.10
4   Fifth   9.98
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace` returns a new string. Also you should first check whether the string contains 'Loan fee:' and then replace it.

So you should do:

```
e=[]
for i in newz:
    if "Loan fee:" in i:
        s = i.replace('Loan fee:','')
        e.append(s)
    else:
        e.append(i)
```